# How to conditionally exclude an angular component from production build?

Tags: angular, environment-variables, production-environment, angular-components

We have a use case where a common repository will be used for different products, let's say Product X and Y. 
The repo has angular components A,B,C.

Specifically, for Product Y, we need to exclude a component B while doing a production build.

Component B has it's selector added, for eg.,  in another component.
 And it's entry in app.module.ts.

I was thinking something on the terms of using an environment variable but not sure how it would apply to our case.

What is the best way to exclude the component conditionally based on which build it is? 
Looking for a temporary, non-scalable solution.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

@Naveen, I think what you'll need to do is further segregate components into modules in your common repository. For eg: In the common repository, Module X will have components A and C whereas Module Y will have component B. Or even further, each component has its own module in the repository. Then you'll need to publish your repository to npm and in this way you can import only the components which you require for your products.

Note: It is usually an industry standard to have the repository of common components that are going to be used across different products as a npm package for better reusability.

Also, in my idea, there's no way yet to conditionally exclude components from the build. You might have to eject and manually configure the webpack config file for this requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs Malhar. Right now our case requires us only to exclude 1 specific component (eg. Component B) from project Y. Project X will have all three, Project Y will only have 2. Do you have any idea if we can achieve this from "fileReplacements" in angular.json?

Comment: I've personally not used 'filereplacements' but it seems to only work for environment files in the Angular documentation. I'm not exactly sure if this can be achieved on build level without touching the webpack config file.

Comment: Also, _"and in this way you can import only the components which you require for your products."_ How exactly would you do this?